# Find the general forumla for this matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A is n x n matrix that in all the places (i, i+1),
there is the number 1, and in the other places there are 0 s . (i goes from 1 to n-1)

Calculate A^k for k= 1,2,..  and (I-A)^-1

I didn't succeed doing it. I only found out that the 1's are creating a triangle that goes up every time the k is bigger.

Comment: You found right. However after $n$ steps the ones vanish and you get zero. Before computing $(1-A)^{1}$, pretend $A = x$, use geometric series technique and then substitute back $A$.

Comment: Do you know how to I find the general A^k formula? how to conclude it?

Comment: Well as you said yourself, $A^{0}= I$, $A^{k}= 0$ for all $k \geq n$, and between $1 < k \leq n-1$, $A^{k}$ has all entries zero except $((1,k+1), (2,k+2),...(n-k, n)$ which are all 1.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Jordan normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you have found out is already great. Have you thought about multiplying
$I - A$ with $I + A + A^2 + A^3 + \ldots$? (You know the sum is not infinite because $A^k$ will become zero somewhere.)

Comment: Do you know how to I find the general A^k formula? how to conclude it?